# StrictMode Policy in api 8 Android

Tags: android, android-strictmode

I am displaying Image in Android App from Hosted Server. So, I need to set `StrictMode Policy`.

 But as I have checked, It requires Api 9 and I want to make it supportable in Api 8 also. So how can I solve this issue ? I am already using this in `AsyncTask`.

**My Code :**

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

If I am not using StrictMode then getting Error.

**Logcat :**

```
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1208)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:388)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:239)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.mytestbuddy.careermirror.Profile$UserProfile.onPostExecute(Profile.java:193)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.mytestbuddy.careermirror.Profile$UserProfile.onPostExecute(Profile.java:1)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
05-08 12:25:08.711: E/AndroidRuntime(27622):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am already using `AsyncTask' I am calling Imagename and then based on Server Image path, I am converting it to Bitmap and displaying Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` you're seeing, read the HTTP response input stream in your `doInBackground()` and not in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: ohk, your mean I receive and convert image to bitmap in `doInBackGround()` ?

Comment: Yes. That runs on the background thread. `onPostExecute()` is on the main UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

`StrictMode` is available from 2.3 only, So you can't use it in 2.2.

There is tow possible ways I can give you.

1. Go with 2.3 [or]
2. Use [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in android.

I go with `AsyncTsk`

I hope this will help you.

Comment: I am already using `AsyncTask' I am calling Imagename and then based on Server Image path, I am converting it to Bitmap and displaying Image.

Comment: Okay. May I know for what purpose you are using `StrictMode`.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` will occur only when you are using network operation on main thread. That's why I am suggesting you to use `AsyncTask`. And do all data retrieving operation on `doInBackground()` method. and the use `onPostExecute()` to update your data in your `Activity`.